# How to get the total search result counts using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the result count when i do a search in amazon. Following is the scenario

Open a new browser instance
Navigate to the amazon.in
Type the search query in the text box
Click on the search button
Validate the web element displaying the number of search results against our expected value

```
public void searchTestOne(){

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.amazon.in");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();        

    driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys("Books");
    driver.findElement(By.className("nav-submit-input")).click();

    int result = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='atfResults']/ul[@id='s-results-list-atf']/li")).size();
    System.out.println(result);   

    driver.close();

    driver.quit();  

    }
```

From above code it displays only count of first page result like "16" where as there so many pages and total result is 2,000+.

Can anyone please suggest on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Webelment used to get total search result count is not correct. Correct element/tag is "h2" with id "s-result-count"

Below line should give you number of search result count:

```
String result = driver.findElement(By.id("s-result-count")).getText().split(" ")[2];
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you are trying to fetch the number of books by counting the number of books enlisted. By this, you would have to navigate to each page, and increase your count accordingly. Rather, you can get the total number of results, alternatively, if you look at the top-left of the page as shown in the image below:

[image]

So, you can get the total count of results from this code as @Surya suggested:

```
String result = driver.findElement(By.id("s-result-count")).getText().split(" ")[2];
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
result = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='atfResults']/ul[@id='s-results-list-atf']/li")).count();
```